# How to draw 2d line time plot with chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to draw line chart with chart.js but all example show single array as data I have 2d data. X is day (date object) and y is price of the product.

I have function like this that create data:

```
function format(data) {
    const result = [];
    Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        var data = {
            label: key,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
            data: value.map(data => ({y: data[0], x: new Date(data[1])}))
        };
        result.push(data);
    });
    return result;
}
```

from documentation I see that I can use object with {x,y} but this render only 2 points.

[image]

the data  output look like this:

```
[
    {
        "label": "cyfrowe.pl",
        "backgroundColor": "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
        "data": [
            {
                "y": 9299,
                "x": "2020-08-01T05:19:28.000Z"
            },
            {
                "y": 9299,
                "x": "2020-08-02T04:15:01.000Z"
            },
```

my code for chart look like this:

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
console.log(ctx);
fetch('price.json')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
      data = format(data);
      console.log(data);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data.slice(0,1), true, 4));
      var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'line',
          data:{ datasets: data }
      });
  });
```

In fact The time should be in days since I have prices for each date at about same hour.

Here is [my demo that is not working](https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/abNKLNJ?editors=0010). (the demo was updated with the answer code).

Comment: Can you possibly provide a StackBlitz?

Comment: @uminder https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/abNKLNJ?editors=0010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your code work, you could use a [scatter](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/scatter.html) chart and add the options `showLine: true` to each `dataset`.

In order to obtain formatted labels for each day, you need to define the x-axis as a [time cartesian axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html) by adding the following configuration to chart `options`.

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    type: 'time',
    time: {
      unit: 'day',
      tooltipFormat: 'MMM DD'
    }
  }] 
}
```

> Please note that Chart.js internally uses Moment.js for the functionality of the [time axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html). Therefore you should use the [bundled version](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html#bundled-build) of Chart.js that includes Moment.js in a single file.

When it comes to also show the labels in the tooltip, add the following to the chart `options`.

```
tooltips: {
  mode: 'point',
  callbacks: {
    title: (tooltipItem, data) => data.datasets[tooltipItem[0].datasetIndex].label
  }
}
```

Please take a look at your amended [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/uminder/pen/OJNExxG?editors=0010).

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to show label on tooltip and day on x axis instead of timestamp?

Comment: @jcubic: I updated my anwer and now also show how to deal with labels and tooltips.

Comment: One more thing if point is the same for two items there is only one label. To fix this I've added `tooltipItem.map(item => data.datasets[item.datasetIndex].label)` and it's perfect.

Comment: @jcubic: Great you got this tooltip issue solved as well.